# Difficulty parsing XML API response with like-named nodes & CDATA

Tags: php, xml

Using PHP & GuzzleHttp client to make API requests.  Receiving XML 1.0 string as the response body.  Have not successfully been able to parse this into something manageable. Please help turn this into an associative array, or preferably, a collection.

Example Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response uri="/crm/private/xml/Contacts/getRecords">
  <result>
    <Contacts>
      <row no="1">
        <FL val="CONTACTID">2762462000000234002</FL>
        <FL val="SMOWNERID">2762462000000128011</FL>
        <FL val="Contact Owner"><![CDATA[Mark Voldermort]]></FL>
        <FL val="Lead Source"><![CDATA[facebook]]></FL>
        <FL val="First Name"><![CDATA[Kimberly]]></FL>
        <FL val="Last Name"><![CDATA[Vandervort]]></FL>
        <FL val="Email"><![CDATA[mvoldermort+fcw.KV@gmail.com]]></FL>
        <FL val="Mobile"><![CDATA[8008230647]]></FL>
        <FL val="SMCREATORID">2762462000000128011</FL>
        <FL val="Created By"><![CDATA[Mark Voldermort]]></FL>
        <FL val="MODIFIEDBY">2762462000000128011</FL>
        <FL val="Modified By"><![CDATA[Mark Voldermort]]></FL>
        <FL val="Created Time"><![CDATA[2018-01-25 17:14:30]]></FL>
        <FL val="Modified Time"><![CDATA[2018-01-25 17:14:30]]></FL>
        <FL val="Full Name"><![CDATA[Kimberly Vandervort]]></FL>
        <FL val="Email Opt Out"><![CDATA[false]]></FL>
        <FL val="Last Activity Time"><![CDATA[2018-01-25 17:14:30]]></FL>
      </row>
      <row no="2">
        <FL val="CONTACTID">2762462000000232001</FL>
        <FL val="SMOWNERID">2762462000000128011</FL>
        <FL val="Contact Owner"><![CDATA[Mark Voldermort]]></FL>
        <FL val="Lead Source"><![CDATA[website]]></FL>
        <FL val="First Name"><![CDATA[Keira]]></FL>
        <FL val="Last Name"><![CDATA[Fisher]]></FL>
        <FL val="Email"><![CDATA[mvoldermort+fcw.KF@gmail.com]]></FL>
        <FL val="Mobile"><![CDATA[8005685583]]></FL>
        <FL val="SMCREATORID">2762462000000128011</FL>
        <FL val="Created By"><![CDATA[Mark Voldermort]]></FL>
        <FL val="MODIFIEDBY">2762462000000128011</FL>
        <FL val="Modified By"><![CDATA[Mark Voldermort]]></FL>
        <FL val="Created Time"><![CDATA[2018-01-25 15:35:35]]></FL>
        <FL val="Modified Time"><![CDATA[2018-01-25 15:35:35]]></FL>
        <FL val="Full Name"><![CDATA[Keira Fisher]]></FL>
        <FL val="Email Opt Out"><![CDATA[false]]></FL>
        <FL val="Last Activity Time"><![CDATA[2018-01-25 15:35:35]]></FL>
      </row>
    </Contacts>
  </result>
</response>
```

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php

Comment: @MadsHansen - I was able to make that work.  Thanks.

Comment: Great! Post a short example as an answer and accept it, so that your question is marked as resolved (and you can pick up a few points)